# Django code not updating in server

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin, gunicorn

I'm using Djnago 1.8.17. I have deployed the code to a remote server, checked that it is up to date, but the changes do not refresh in the web page. 
Things I've tried so far:

- Restarted gunicorn and nginx
- Using manage.py instead of gunicorn
- Clear memcached
- Restarted server
- Delete all .pyc files
- Open in incognito

I've this module that is working fine in other servers, but for some reason this one is showing an old version.

Comment: did your change git branch? and what result if you try to run `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`?

Comment: Yes. It runs fine, but with old code

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from static files
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

you try to update them with

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```